# Read credit card and fill a form in the browser?

Tags: ios, web, mobile-safari, payment, credit-card

I was wondering if there was any way to have a Credit Card reader connected to an iOS device, and when swiping a card, pre-fill a form in the browser. Basically have the Card reader act as a Keyboard and with some Javascript on the page, fill the right info in the right fields in the current page. I'm looking to do this purely on a Web Page with Safari.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this from Safari on iOS. Safari would have to support this feature, which it does not.

Instead, you could create your own app that interfaces with a credit card reader and uses a web view as a mock Internet browser. You can interact with the content of a web view via [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a).